# map Flux of Fluxes of Fluxes to an object with List of Lists of Lists

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am crawling an API and build up the following data structure:

```
public class Organization {
    String id;
    String name;
    Flux<Space> spaces;
}

public class Space {
    String id;
    String name;
    Flux<Application> applications;
}

public class Application {
    String id;
    String name;
    Flux<Process> processes;
}

public class Process {
    String processId;
    Integer instances;
}
```

Now, I would like to persist objects of the class `Organization`.
To do that, I created for all classes prefixed classes like `PersistedOrganization` with `List<Space> spaces` instead of `Flux`es and would now have to map the objects I receive in the following snippet:

```
cfOperations.organizations().list()
                .parallel(2)
                .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .map(this::processOrganization)
                .subscribe(this::persistOrganization);
```

I already subscribe to the initial `Flux` and have now access to objects of an `Organization`.

Unfortunately I'm lost and cannot see how I can unwrap those nested Fluxes to Lists. I already tried using `Mono<List<Space>>` but this didn't seem to solve the issue either for my limited knowledge.

I tried `flatMap()` but this gives me single objects of `Process`es at the end and it looks like I lose the intermediate results like `Space` and `Application`

I'm thankful for any food for thought. For me it's important to hold an object of the root (`Organization`) at the end and not just a handful of leaves (`Process`) which would be straight-forward with `.subscribe()` to every subsequent `Flux`.

Comment: Can you share more of your code? It would be interesting to see how you retrieve organizations (list method?) and how fluxes of processes, applications and spaces are created. This might help finding a non-blocking solution.

Comment: tbh i would not use `Flux` as a datatype to store values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I come with without blocking; I shortened hierarchy by 1, to make it more readable, but expanding it is trivial. Basically it's just a sequence of `flatMap` - `collectList` - `map` repeated for each level.

```
cfOperations.organizations().list()
        .flatMap(organization -> organization.spaces
                .flatMap(space -> space.applications
                        .map(application -> new PersistedApplication(application.id, application.name))
                        .collectList()
                        .map(persistedApplications -> new PersistedSpace(space.id, space.name, persistedApplications))
                )
                .collectList()
                .map(persistedSpaces -> new PersistedOrganization(organization.id, organization.name, persistedSpaces))
        )
        .subscribe(this::persistOrganization);
```

Anyway, I don't think that creating POJOs with Fluxes as properties is good idea. For example, after cold Flux is subsribed, all it's elements are 'lost' for other subsribers - that's not the way I would expect POJO to work ;) Too much uncertainty.

Comment: Thank you very much. This did the trick. I wasn't able to wrap my head around it without your example :-)

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty you'll find here is that there's no way to create a `List` from a `Flux` without blocking somewhere along the line, which defeats the point of using reactive streams somewhat. You may do better to adapt your persistence API so that it can work of the `Flux` objects directly, rather than just standard Java collections.

That being said, if you still *really* want to do it this way, I'd recommend creating new constructors in the `PersistedX` set of classes, so they look like the following:

```
class PersistedOrganization {

    String id;
    String name;
    List<PersistedSpace> spaces;

    public PersistedOrganization(Organization org) {
        this.id = org.id;
        this.name = org.name;
        this.spaces = org.spaces.collectList().block().stream().map(PersistedSpace::new);
    }
}
```

(and so on for the other classes.)

When you've done that, persisting the whole chain comes down to just:

```
List<PersistedOrganization> pl = orgList.stream().map(PersistedOrganization::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

...but as before, understand that this will block at every step, so is far from ideal.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insights, Michael. Unless a magical possibility appears to do this without blocking, I gladly accept your answer.

Comment: note that `collectList()` is tailored to convert a `Flux<T>` to a `Mono<List<T>>`, and doesn't really block: upon receiving each `T` source element, it internally aggregates the element into a `List` that it only emits when it receives the `onComplete` signal. But I tend to agree that POJO with `Flux` attributes is not necessarily a good idea.